# Механизм Attention для RNN

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow, deeplearning4j

Модель Encoder-Decoder для реализации задачи Seq2Seq:

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(INPUT_VOCAB_SIZE, EMB_SIZE)
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(H_SIZE, 
                                         return_sequences=False, 
                                         return_state=True)
        
    def call(self, x):
        out = self.embed(x)
        _, h, c = self.lstm(out)
        state = (h, c)
        return state

class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(TARGET_VOCAB_SIZE, EMB_SIZE)
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(H_SIZE, 
                                         return_sequences=True, 
                                         return_state=True)
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(TARGET_VOCAB_SIZE, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, x, init_state):
        out = self.embed(x)
        out, h, c = self.lstm(out, initial_state=init_state)
        out = self.fc(out)
        state = (h, c)
        return out, state
```

Далее объединяем в единую систему:

```
encoder_model = Encoder()
decoder_model = Decoder()

encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))

enc_state = encoder_model(encoder_inputs)
decoder_outputs, _ = decoder_model(decoder_inputs, enc_state)

seq2seq = tf.keras.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

Имеется реализация механизма Attention от TensorFlow:

```
tf.keras.layers.Attention()
```

Вопрос: Как данную реализацию можно внедрить в имеющуюся систему, чтобы Attention отрабатывал?

Сломано множество копий, вариантов реализации и попыток.

Ни это - https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras

Ни это - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946995/how-to-build-a-attention-model-with-keras

Ни это - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention?hl=ru  не работает.